Ошибка обнаружения указанного сервера/экземпляра SQL Server, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified, ASP NET Core
У меня локальный сервер ASP NET Core MVC, локальная база данных SQL Server Express.
Создал таблицы в базе данных, генерация моделей через Scaffold-DbContext прошла успешно, подключение к ядру через SSMS проходит, в контроллер передается контекст с правильной строкой подключения(проверил).
Далее в методе контроллера в этот момент - var backupTable = _context.Products.ToList();
вылетает ошибка :
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"
В менеджере конфигураций служба SQL Server выполняется,TCP/IP разрешено, пробовал отключать брандмауэр, строка подключения точно верна, в свойствах сервера в SSMS стоит галочка на "Разрешить удаленные соединения с этим сервером", больше не знаю куда копать.
Но всё же допускаю, может в строке подключения я должен был указать что-то еще "Server=DESKTOP-ATJOK7H\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MSCompleX;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"?

Добавьте в строку соединения Encrypt=False

Помогло, спасибо
